# Does cl.h work for C++?

Tags: c++, opencl

I know OpenCL has a C++ binder, but I use a third party library which is currently only working with CL.h. I want to write my program in C++. Is it safe to include cl.h in a C++ program and work with that in C style?

I saw some examples of including cl.h in C++ and they seem to be working. However, I don't know for sure. Is there any specific situation that may cause problems?

Comment: Did you try to do it? If it builds, there's no reason to believe it won't work at runtime.

Comment: @zneak Usually mixing up C++ and C wouldn't be a problem. But I think there is a possibility that some data structure could be stored/handled differently in C++, and when they are passed to OpenCL library, bad things will happen at runtime.

Comment: in C++, C-compatible structures (structures in the flat namespace with no methods or constructors/destructors) are called "POD types" (Plain Old Data types), and are binary-compatible between C and C++. So if you have a C header, you shouldn't have to worry about differences brought in by C++, as long as the header is wrapped in a `extern "C" {` block when included in C++ code. (There _could_ be alignment issues if you use a different compiler, but that would have nothing to do with C++ itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is a C/C++ header with proper "extern "C" " guards.

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.0/cl.h

Answer (score 2):

If it's a C header, you can wrap it in `extern "C"` directives:

```
extern "C"
{
   #include "CL.h"
}
```

this tells the linker not to apply name mangling when looking for the functions declared in the header.

Comment: Shouldn't they be doing that themselves? I mean, it seems to me that most C libraries have `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif` statements protecting inclusion.

Comment: @zneak not if it's a C header (IDK if it is)